# Immediate Neighborhood And Continuous Functions

Tags: calculus

In many books it is written that a function is continuous at a point if there are no breaks or jumps in the immediate neighborhood of that point but if we consider the function $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational, it jumps infinitely many times in the neighborhood of $0$ although it is continuous at $x=0$

Comment: I've read many books, but none which claim that. Anyway, what's the question?

Comment: I think you've got it reversed.  The book probably says that if there is a break or a jump, it's discontinuous, not the other way around.

Comment: I doubt there are textbooks that use that exact wording, but you may be referring to how some text books informally try to give students some intuition for what continuity means, as opposed to how those books formally define continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the stories about "breaks" and "jumps". Whoever mentions those terms is trying to give you the *intuition* about continuity, rather than rigorously define it. Or, let me challenge you to first find a rigorous definition of a "break" or a "jump", and then we can talk about whether your function $f$ has breaks or jumps at $0$.

On the other hand, the rigorous definition of *continuity of a function $f$ at the point $a\in\text{domain}(f)$* (which is to say that $f$ is defined in $a$) is:

$$f\text{ is continuous in }a \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$$

which is then equivalent to (by the definition of the limit):

$$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in\text{domain}(f))(|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon)$$

... or one of a few equivalent definitions. (See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function.)

This definition is perfectly rigorous, and it actually happens to match our intuition in "tame" cases (without intention to discuss what "tame" precisely means ... your function probably isn't one of those), but it takes a course in Analysis to get completely used to it...

This definition has also got very important generalisations to: functions of multiple variables, complex functions, functions mapping "surfaces" (manifolds) to each other, all the way up to the very abstract concept of functions between topological spaces. At that point, the intuition about "breaks" and "jumps" certainly ceases to be satisfactory (if not a lot earlier!).

Back to your function: you can prove that it satisfies this definition for $a=0$, because $|f(x)|\le|x|$ for every $x$, so for $a=0$ you can pick $\delta=\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. (I would leave to you to fill in the details.)

Answer (score 0):

At x=0, In neighborhood x can either be rational or irrational. In both cases x is rational or irrational , f(x) is equals to zero. That's why it's only point where function is continuous.

Imagine it's graph , there will be infinite jumps around zero ,since there are infinite rational and irrational numbers in between two infinitesimally small numbers , but even after it for a very very small interval there will be continuity.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, a function $f(x)$ is discontinuous in $x_0$ if the limit oscillations in $x_0$ have a non-zero supremum i.e. $$f(x)\text{ is discontinuous in }x_0\iff \limsup_{x\to x_0}|\text{osc}f(x)|=l> 0$$For example for $f(x)=\sin {1\over x}$ in $x_0=0$ the supremum is $\infty$ and for the function defined here the supremum is $0$.